# Regex for 12th character must be Alphabetic or nil

Tags: asp.net, regex

Can someone please give me some idea of regular expression for following requirements :

**Twelve Digit String {First 11 character to be Numeric and  {12th character must be  Alphabetic or nil}**

I tried this : `"^\d{11}$"` which allows only first 11 digit numeric characters .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? I suppose nil means end of string...

```
^\d{11}[a-zA-Z]?$
```

http://rubular.com/r/AhUsJHljD0

Answer (score 2):

A non regex approach:

```
bool match = str.Length == 12 
        && str.Take(11).All(Char.IsDigit) 
        && (Char.IsLetter(str[11]) || str[11] == '\0');
```